# Clash for windows: how to switch node period periodically?

Tags: clash

I am really newbie on Clash. What i need is to change my ip address periodically, then how to config or write some script for Clash for windows in order to achieve this?

Currently I have to manually click after some minutes by some minutes past, in order to change my local ip.